# How I can write polymeric reaction in latex

Tags: chemfig

Is it possible write this reaction in latex ?

[image]

I used this code, but the "image" of raction is very big. How I can reduce it ?

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
    \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
    \usepackage{chemfig}
    \usepackage{chemmacros}
    \usepackage{enumitem}


    \begin{document}
    \newcommand\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}
    \def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
    \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
    \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
    \chemmove{%
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
    {$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
    width0pt\right.$};%
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
    {$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim
    width0pt\right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}}
    \setpolymerdelim()

    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\setcounter{enumi}{3}
 \item\setatomsep{1.8em}
\chemfig{R-O-Si(-[2]OR)(-[6]OR)-[@{downleft,0.9},2]O-Si(-[2]OH)(-[6]OR)-[@{downright,0.4},2]OH}

%\schemestart
%\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[\parbox{5cm}{\centering -m \si{H_2O}\\-k ROH}]}[,1.8]
%\schemestop
%\arrow(.mid east--.mid west){->[\parbox{5cm}{\centering -m \si{H_2O}\\-k ROH}]}[,1.8]
%\setchemrel{1pt}{}{6em}
\chemrel[-m {\si{H_2O}//-k ROH}]{->}
%\chemrel[$-\mathrm{m\,H_2O}$]{->}
%\arrow{->[\parbox{5cm}{\centering -m \si{H_2O}\\-k ROH}]}
 \chemfig{-O-Si(-[2]O-[2]Si([2]-)([4]-)-)(-[6]O-[4]R)-O-Si(-[2]O-[8]H)(-[6]O-[6]Si([6]-)([4]-)-)-O-Si(-[2]O-[2]Si([2]-)([4]-)-)(-[6]O-[8]H)-O-Si([2]-)([6]-)([8]-)}

\makebraces[40pt,40pt]{n}{downleft}{downright}
\end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I propose the following solution. I've made a number of changes:

- First of all I find your use of `enumerate` a bit strange. It *looks* like you want equation numbers for your reactions. If that's it then I'd use an `equation` environment. With the class option `leqno` its numbers will be placed on the left.
- I'd still use `chemfig`'s `\schemestart ... \schemestop` mechanism. In it the `\arrow` command can be used to have the reaction downwards instead to left.  This can be done by using the optional `<angle>` argument:

  ```
  \arrow{<arrow spec>}[<angle>,<length>]
  ```

  I use an angle of `-90` below. In order for the label *not* to rotate you can use the `*` syntax of `\arrow` labels:

  ```
  \arrow{->[*{<angle>}<label>]}[-90]
  ```

  Using `*{0}` will give the label a horizontal orientation.
- This one is more a cosmetic thing: I use *a lot* more indentation inside `\chemfig{}` which makes the formulae much more readable.
- For placing several lines on the arrow I use a `tabular`. This is more comfortable than a `\parbox` because there's no need to specify a width.
- I use math mode for the stoichiometric factors.
- Last I changed the syntax of `\makebraces` a bit into a more LaTeX-like syntax and renamed it into `\makepolymerbraces`. This is only my personal taste...

The complete example gives:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemformula}

% polymer delimiters:
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\polymer@delimleft{#1}\def\polymer@delimright{#2}}

\newcommand*\makepolymerbraces[5]{%
  \edef\polymer@delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
  \edef\polymer@delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
  \chemmove{
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\polymer@delimvshift)]
      {$
       \left\polymer@delimleft
         \vrule height\polymer@delimhalfdim depth\polymer@delimhalfdim width0pt
       \right.
      $};
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\polymer@delimvshift)]
      {$
        \left.
          \vrule height\polymer@delimhalfdim depth\polymer@delimhalfdim width0pt
        \right\polymer@delimright_{\rlap{#3}}
      $};
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{equation}
  \setpolymerdelim[]\setatomsep{2em}
  \schemestart
    $x$
    \chemfig{
      R-O-Si
        (-[2]OR)
        (-[6]OR)
      -[@{b1,.6},1.5]
      O-Si
        (-[2]OH)
        (-[6]OR)
      -[@{b2},2]
      OH
    }
    \arrow{%
      ->[*{0}%
      \begin{tabular}{c}
        \ch{$-m$ H2O} \\
        \ch{$-k$ ROH}
      \end{tabular}%
      ]%
    }[-90,1.5]
    $z$
    \chemfig{
      -O-Si
        (-[2]O-[2]Si([2]-)([4]-)-)
        (-[6]O-[4]R)
      -O-Si
        (-[2]O-[8]H)
        (-[6]O-[6]Si([6]-)([4]-)-)
      -O-Si
        (-[2]O-[2]Si([2]-)([4]-)-)
        (-[6]O-[8]H)
      -O-Si
        ([2]-)
        ([6]-)
      -
    }
  \schemestop
  \makepolymerbraces{30pt}{30pt}{$n$}{b1}{b2}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the package `chemfig` for this. For the braces you should have a look in chapter 12.5 of [its documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig).

Here is some code to start with:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\setatomsep{7mm}
\chemfig{x\,Et-O-Si(-[2]OEt)(-[6]OEt)-O-Si(-[2]OH)(-[6]OEt)-OH}
\chemrel[$-\mathrm{m\,H_2O}$]{->}
\chemfig{z-O-Si(-[2]O-[2]Si([2]-)([4]-)-)(-[6]O-[4]Et)-O-Si-O-Si-O-Si-}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the `x` is not part of the molecule but a stoichiometric factor, just like the `m` in front of H2O and the `z` later on. As such they're variables and should be typeset as such (`$x$`, `$m$`...) and should not be part of `\chemfig{...}`. Also, I would think the `chemfig`'s scheme commands would be a better solution than the `\chemrel` thingy. It would for example allow for a vertical arrangement in order to have a bit more space horizontally...

Comment: thank you. How can I put two things in arrow ?

Comment: @user46548 see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113138/chemfig-new-line-reaction-scheme