# Chemical Structures

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I have trouble in entering the following chemical reaction in LaTeX. I will be very grateful for every help.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome to TeX.SE. Could you add a minimal working example, please? You can visit the link http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Chemistry.

Comment: Thank you Sebastiano.
I used \chemfig as below but it does not exactly what I need:
\chemfig{n(CH_2(=[:0]CHCOOH))}

Comment: @Reza search the chemfig manual for polymers

Comment: Reza, yet I have not undestood your picture because I have not your source. Add your source and a figure with your hand. I'm not an expert of chemical structures, sorry.

Comment: See for example also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96633/ and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188615/

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned already in the comments: the `chemfig` manual has a section about those kind of schemes. In an example in the manual there are the macro `\makebraces` and `\setpolymerdelims` defined which can be used here. A remark for the first formula: parentheses have a special meaning inside `chemfig`'s formulas (branching). In order to have them printed they have to be enclosed with braces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand*\delimleft{}
\newcommand*\delimright{}
\newcommand*\makebraces{}
\newcommand*\delimhalfdim{}
\newcommand*\delimvshift{}
\newcommand*\setpolymerdelim[2]{\def\delimleft{#1}\def\delimright{#2}}
\def\makebraces[#1,#2]#3#4#5{%
  \edef\delimhalfdim{\the\dimexpr(#1+#2)/2}%
  \edef\delimvshift{\the\dimexpr(#1-#2)/2}%
  \chemmove{
    \node[at=(#4),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$\left\delimleft\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
        \right.$};
    \node[at=(#5),yshift=(\delimvshift)]
      {$\left.\vrule height\delimhalfdim depth\delimhalfdim width0pt
        \right\delimright_{\rlap{$\scriptstyle#3$}}$};}
}  
\setpolymerdelim()


\begin{document}

\schemestart
  $n$ \chemfig{{(}CH_2=CHCOOH{)}}
  \arrow(--.-165)
  \chemfig{-[@{b1}]CH_2-CH(-[2]COOH)-[@{b2}]}
\schemestop
\makebraces[5pt,5pt]{n}{b1}{b2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Further references/examples:

- [How to draw parentheses inside chemfig?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96633/)
- [How I can write polymeric reaction in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188615/)

#### Remarks:

The `chemmacros` package has a module `polymers` which defines a `\makepolymerdelims`. Using it one doesn't need to add definitions to the preamble. However, using it may only make sense if `chemmacros` is used anyway. The code then becomes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

\chemsetup{
  modules = {polymers} ,
  polymers/delimiters = ()
}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
  $n$ \chemfig{{(}CH_2=CHCOOH{)}}
  \arrow(--.-165)
  \chemfig{-[@{b1}]CH_2-CH(-[2]COOH)-[@{b2}]}
\schemestop
\makepolymerdelims{5pt}{b1}{b2}

\end{document}
```