# How to add a vertical space in the text above/under the arrow in the chemfig package

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I'm trying to add a vertical space between `H$_{2}$O$_{2}$ 30\%` and `\SI{25}{\degreeCelsius}, \SI{30}{\minute}`, but I can't. Do you have any idea how to do it?

[image]

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\newcommand*\pkg[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\scalebox{0.9}{
\schemestart
\chemname{
\scriptsize
\chemfig[yshift=15pt]{*6((-(*6(=-=([:150]-[,,,,white]R|^1([:0]-))-=-)))=-(-(*6(-=-([:30]-[,,,,white]R|^2([:180]-))=-=)))(=[::60]O))}
}{\textbf{1}}
\arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
{->[LDH, solvente][H$_{2}$O$_{2}$ 30\%, \\ \SI{25}{\degreeCelsius}, \SI{30}{\minute}]}[0,2.0]
\chemname{
\scriptsize
\chemfig[yshift=15pt]{*6((-(*6(=-=([:150]-[,,,,white]R|^1([:0]-))-=-)))-(-[:210]O(-[:90]))-(-(*6(-=-([:30]-[,,,,white]R|^2([:180]-))=-=)))(=[::60]O))}
}{\textbf{2}}
\schemestop
}
\caption{Reacción de epoxidación. Oxidación de la doble ligadura de la chalcona en presencia de un peróxido de hidrógeno y una base orgánica.}
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Based on your verbal description, that would be called horizontal space...?  So which is it?

Comment: In other words, add a space as if I had occupied the enter key. I mean, put the temperature and time under the hydrogen peroxide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know whether this is the best, but I made a `\vbox` of your text: this way it can be correctly rendered as you wish:

```
            \documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
            \usepackage{chemfig}
            \usepackage{siunitx}
            \usepackage{chemnum}
            \newcommand*\pkg[1]{\textsf{#1}}
            \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

            \begin{document}

            \begin{figure}[!htbp]
            \centering
            \scalebox{0.9}{%
            \schemestart
            \chemname{%
            \scriptsize%
            \chemfig[yshift=28pt]{*6((-(*6(=-=([:150]-[,,,,white]R|^1([:0]-))-=-)))=-(-(*6(-=-([:30]-[,,,,white]R|^2([:180]-))=-=)))(=[::60]O))}
            }{\textbf{1}}
            \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
            {->[LDH, solvente][\vbox{H$_{2}$O$_{2}$ 30\%,\\ \SI{25}{\degreeCelsius}, \SI{30}{\minute}}]}[0,2.0]
            \chemname{%
            \scriptsize%
            \chemfig[yshift=28pt]{*6((-(*6(=-=([:150]-[,,,,white]R|^1([:0]-))-=-)))-(-[:210]O(-[:90]))-(-(*6(-=-([:30]-[,,,,white]R|^2([:180]-))=-=)))(=[::60]O))}
            }{\textbf{2}}
            \schemestop
            }
            \caption{Reacción de epoxidación. Oxidación de la doble ligadura de la chalcona en presencia de un peróxido de hidrógeno y una base orgánica.}
            \label{fig:3}
            \end{figure}

            \end{document}
```

Yielding

[image]

**EDIT**

Please *do mind* that I had to play around with the `yshift`, because it did not give me a correct picture otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea I used in [Chemfig new line reaction scheme](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113138/chemfig-new-line-reaction-scheme/113148#113148) – it patches the nodes of the arrow. The code below has a few other enhancements. There is no need for the `yshift` for example. Also I'd use a package like `chemnum` for the numbering of the compounds instead of doing it manually…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemnum,siunitx}

\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter
% \xpatchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
% the starred version replaces all instances of <search>
\xpatchcmd*\CF@arrow@display@label@a{node[}{node[align=center,}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \setatomsep{1.3em}
  \schemestart
    \chemname{%
      \chemfig{
        *6((-(*6(=-=([:150]-[,,,,white]R|^1([:0]-))-=-)))
        =-(-(*6(-=-([:30]-[,,,,white]R|^2([:180]-))=-=)))(=[::60]O))
      }}{\cmpd{one}}
    \arrow{%
      ->[LDH, solvente]%
        [\chemfig{H_2O_2} \SI{30}{\percent}, \\ \SI{25}{\celsius}, \SI{30}{\minute}]%
      }[0,2.0]
    \chemname{%
      \chemfig{
        *6((-(*6(=-=([:150]-[,,,,white]R|^1([:0]-))-=-)))
        -(-[:210]O(-[:90]))-(-(*6(-=-([:30]-[,,,,white]R|^2([:180]-))=-=)))(=[::60]O))
      }}{\cmpd{two}}
  \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]