# Long Chemfig reaction scheme in two lines above each other

Tags: vertical-alignment, width, chemfig

The reaction scheme shown below is to long to fit in one line. I would like to place the two left compounds atop one another, so the `+` is in the middle between them, vertically centered with the arrow.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \setchemfig{fixed length=true, atom sep=1.5em, arrow offset=6pt}
    \def\x{\vphantom{C}}

\begin{document}

\setchemfig{arrow coeff=1.65}
\centering\small
\schemestart
    \chemfig{\x-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt,depth=29pt]{li}{re}
    \+
    \chemfig{\x-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt,depth=29pt,indice=m]{li}{re}
    \arrow{<->>[$T$, $t$, $\Delta p_{\ce{H2O}}$][]}
    \chemfig{\x-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt,depth=29pt,indice=n+m]{li}{re}
    \+
    \chemfig{H_2O} \
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** As @leandriis pointed out, simply putting the arrow text in a `\parbox`, such as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113138/chemfig-new-line-reaction-scheme) question, solves the issue.

**EDIT 2:** I forgot to add a H and a OH group at the sides on all molecules, making them even longer. Thus, the original issue still exists and is even worse.

**MWE 2:**

```
\setchemfig{arrow label sep=5pt}
\centering\small
\schemestart
    \chemfig{\x H-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]OH}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt,depth=29pt]{li}{re}
    \+
    \chemfig{\x H-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]OH}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt,depth=29pt,indice=m]{li}{re}
    \arrow{<->>[\parbox{5cm}{\centering $T$, $t$,\\$\Delta p_{\ce{H2O}}$}][]}
    \chemfig{\x H-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]OH}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt,depth=29pt,indice=n+m]{li}{re}
    \+
    \chemfig{H_2O}
\schemestop
```

[image]

Comment: Probably you could introduce a linebreak in the text above the arrow (see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113138/134144) and keep the whole reaction in a single line.

Comment: that's much easier, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a vertical `\subscheme` and invisible arrows it is rather easy:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\setchemfig{fixed length=true, atom sep=1.5em, arrow offset=6pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \def\x{\vphantom{C}}
  \setchemfig{arrow label sep=5pt}
  \small
  \schemestart
      \subscheme[-90]{%
      \chemfig{\x H-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]OH}
      \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt,depth=29pt]{li}{re}
      \arrow{0}[,.3]
      \+{0pt,1em}
      \arrow{0}[,.3]
      \chemfig{\x H-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]OH}
      \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt,depth=29pt,indice=m]{li}{re}
    }
    \arrow{<->>[{\begin{tabular}{c}$T$, $t$,\\$\Delta p_{\ce{H2O}}$\end{tabular}}][]}
    \chemfig{\x H-[@{li}]N(-[2]H)-\x|{(}CH_2{)}_{11}|\x-C(=[6]O)-[@{re}]OH}
    \polymerdelim[delimiters={[]},height=25pt,depth=29pt,indice=n+m]{li}{re}
    \+
    \chemfig{H_2O}
  \schemestop
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]